# How to store and retrieve List<MyClass> object using RxPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, rx-android

I’m using the GsonPreferenceAdapter as shown [here](https://github.com/chemouna/HarryPotterBooks/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mounacheikhna/harrypotterbooks/data/prefs/GsonPreferenceAdapter.java) with [Prateek's RxPreferences](http://f2prateek.com/2015/10/05/rx-preferences/) library.

My Fragment Class Code:

```
@Inject RxSharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
@Inject Gson gson;

List<MyClass> my_class_list;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Binding and Inject go here.

    Class listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyClass>>(){}.getClass();
    GsonPreferenceAdapter<List<MyClass>> adapter = new GsonPreferenceAdapter<>(gson, listType, new ArrayList<MyClass>(), GsonPreferenceAdapter.SyntaxExceptionBehavior.NULL);
    my_class_list = sharedPreferences.getObject("pref_myclass", new ArrayList<>(), adapter).get();

    if(my_class_list == null)
        Timber.i("Tis null.");

    Timber.i("Printing MyClass items...");
    for(MyClass item: my_class_list)
        Timber.i("MyClass: " + item);

}

@OnClick(R.id.add)
public void add() {

    MyClass entry = new MyClass("Count Dracula", "12345");
    my_class_list.add(entry);

    Class listType = new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>(){}.getClass();
    GsonPreferenceAdapter<List<MyClass>> adapter = new GsonPreferenceAdapter<>(gson, listType, new ArrayList<MyClass>(), GsonPreferenceAdapter.SyntaxExceptionBehavior.NULL);
    sharedPreferences.getObject("pref_myclass", new ArrayList<>(), adapter).set(my_class_list);

    Timber.i("Data Saved");
    return false;
}
```

When I run it the first time, it doesn't log **Tis null** which means my_class_list is not null. And I click on the button to call add() and this returns **Data Saved** suggesting that it is indeed saved. When I re-launch the app it crashes at the for loop with:

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
```

It also prints **Tis null** so I'm surprised how the null was added. What's going on here, and how to solve this?

Contents of MyClass:

```
public class MyClass {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("number")
    @Expose
    public String number;

    public MyClass(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", number='" + number + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out on my own. I’ve put the answer if anyone else comes across the same issue. The problem was with GsonPreferenceAdapter which I ripped off. I changed the Class to Type and everything worked fine.

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>(){}.getType();
GsonPreferenceAdapter<List< MyClass >> adapter = new GsonPreferenceAdapter<>(gson, type, new ArrayList<>(), GsonPreferenceAdapter.SyntaxExceptionBehavior.NULL);
my_class_list = sharedPreferences.getObject("pref_myclass", new ArrayList<>(), adapter).get();
```